# Como criar ListView com dados do SQLite em Fragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragment

Como faço para inserir os dados do SQLite nesse listview do meu código:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] sCheeseStrings = {"Emerson","Simone","Samara"};
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sCheeseStrings));
    }
```

os dados que eu quero exibir são 'TITLE' e 'AUTHOR'.

estou tentando isso:

```
public class TabActivity extends Fragment { 
    private final DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
    public class TabActivity extends Fragment {
    private final DataBaseHandler db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        db.addBook(new Book("Android Application Development Cookbook", "Wei Meng Lee"));   
        db.addBook(new Book("Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide", "Bill Phillips and Brian Hardy"));       
        db.addBook(new Book("Learn Android App Development", "Wallace Jackson"));


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab, container, false);

        return rootView;
        List<Book> cursor = db.getAllBooks();

        String title;
        String author;
        String[] from = { title, author }; 
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1 }; 

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to);
    }
}
```

Mas está dando um erro "The method SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, List, String[], int[]) is undefined for the type TabActivity" .
O que pode ser?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo @Emerson Barcellos, você está dando um comando return no método `onCreateView()` antes de executar as instruções que criam o seu `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Coloque a instrução return para o final do método e a criação do cursor antes da instrução `return rootView`. Caso minha resposta tenha ajudado, marque-a como aceita.

Comment: Outra coisa. Veja as perguntas que você fez no seu perfil e observe se não tem nenhuma pendente. Alguma pergunta que você fez e esqueceu de dar resposta caso tenha conseguido achar sozinho a resposta ou que alguém respondeu. Tente evitar fazer perguntas e deixá-las largadas sem seu retorno. Isso mantém o site Stack Overflow bom.

Comment: Puxa @LucasSantos eu tô quase desistindo de usar Fragment, em TabHost e Activity eu tenho um app funcionando, e eu quero mudar, mas eu não sei usar o maldito Fragment. Bom vamos lá...vou colocar o print do erro, por quê será que dá erro?

Comment: por que você está usando TabActivity? Essa classe está obsoleta.

Comment: Ok @LucasSantos muito obrigado. Vou buscar alternativas para resolver o meu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser pode utilizar `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
String[] from = { id, titulo }; // Colunas que você quer exibir
int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text1 }; // ID's dos componentes que estão configurados no recurso de layout que será passado para o construtor do SimpleCursorAdapter.

Cursor cursor = retornaMeuCursor(); // Aqui você faz a busca no banco de dados e retorna o seu cursor com os dados.

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to);
```